# Using Semaphore in a scoped service

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

Does a semaphore inside a method of a scoped service give access only to one person at a time ?

```
public class MyScopedService
{
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1); 

    public async Task SomeMethod()
    {
        await semaphore.WaitAsync();
        try
        {
            // Access the shared resource here
        }
        finally
        {
            semaphore.Release();
        }
    }
}
```

register in DI:

```
 services.AddScoped<MyScopedService>();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It highly depends on how you execute the code and how you host your application.

1. `SomeMethod` is invoked by caller multiple times in parallel. Then the semaphore would throttle access to the shared resource, as you would use the same instance of `MyScopedService` and so, you'd use the same semaphore and throttling would occur.
2. If you want the the thottlong to work across the application, you would need to have some shared `Semaphore`, that would be application-wise, or take look into other ways (`lock`, `Monitor` class). Or you could have singleton class with the semaphore, which would take care of invoking the method.
3. BUT none above would work if the code could be executed by multiple instances (for example if you're hosting app in cloud and having multiplle instances of the application). Then you would need to apply distributed locks, I highly recommend [this nuget package](https://github.com/madelson/DistributedLock).

Answer (score 2):

No, because you create a new `SemaphoreSlim` for each `ScopedService` instance, and it's bound scoped i.e. a new `ScopedService` and a new `SemaphoreSlim` is created for each request. If you want a semaphore that will give access only to one person (request) at a time overall, you will need to create it in a service that is bound in the global scope (a singleton).